# Angular 2 router

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an Angular 2 test app. I'm using the new router and it seemed to be working fine this was my code:

```
export class Topbar {
    constructor(@Inject(Router) router: Router) {
        router.config([
            {path: '/displays', as: 'display', component: Display}
        ]);
    }
}
```

This works now as soon as I add a second route like this I get an error:

```
export class Topbar {
    constructor(@Inject(Router) router: Router) {
        router.config([
            {path: '/', as: 'home', component: MyApp},
            {path: '/displays', as: 'display', component: Display}
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Configuration '/' conflicts with existing route '/'
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess,

1. Your router config goes in your App component
2. and '/' routes to component: Home rather than MyApp

something like this

```
export class MyApp {

  constructor(@Inject(Router) router: Router) {
    router.config([
      { path: '/', as: 'home', component: Home },
      { path: '/about', as: 'about', component: About }
    ]);
  }
}
```